# If operator in groovy sql select statement

Tags: sql, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I would like to use the if operator in the select statement, using an executeQuery command.
Something like:

```
def tmpRec = BankStatement.executeQuery("select   SUM(IF(operation='CREDIT',cashAmount,-1*cashAmount)) from BankStatement group by portfolio,currency,code")
```

go
but the IF operator doesn't work.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not know Groovy SQL, in most DBMS the CASE statement is used as a conditional statement. Perhaps the following will work:

```
def tmpRec = BankStatement.executeQuery("select SUM(CASE WHEN operation='CREDIT' THEN cashAmount ELSE (-1*cashAmount) END) from BankStatement group by portfolio,currency,code")
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, it works, I have just to put -1*cashAmount between parenthesis. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you NiBE. I revised the answer to include parentheses as per your comment.